# On conglomerates' axiom of choice(Category theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, axiom-of-choice

There is a requirement of conglomerate(collection of classes) which demands the following property. Axiom of choice for conglomerates: For each surjection between congomerates $f:X\to Y$, there is an injection $g:Y\to X$ with $f\circ g=Id_Y$. I do not see why this must be required. And is this implying that X and Y has the same cardinality?  Can someone illuminate this a bit? And why this is called axiom of choice?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you understand what is the axiom of choice for sets? Where does the fact that you're dealing with conglomerates get into the question?

Comment: I am only familiar with axiom choice for sets in its statement but I never use it before. I do not see why there is necesscity of axiom of choice of conglomerates and why $|X|=|Y|$ if there is a surjection?

Comment: The necessity for **what**? The second part of your comment doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Under these conditions in a way $g\circ f$ connects every fibre of $f$ to an element of that fibre. In that sence it can be recognized as a choice-function. This is a link to AC.

Comment: User45765 What book/text are you referring to? The "Joy of cats" perhaps?

Comment: Yep. It is joys of cats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom of choice is a set theoretic axiom which states that if $X$ is a family of non-empty sets, then there is a function $f$ whose domain is $X$, such that $f(x)\in x$ for each $x\in X$.

We call these choice functions because they choose an element from each $x\in X$.

It is equivalent, however, to say that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a surjection, then there is an injective function $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g=\operatorname{Id}_Y$. To see why these two are equivalent, define $X_y=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$, then $\{X_y\mid y\in Y\}$ is a family of non-empty sets, and therefore it has a choice function, which we can easily prove to be injective with the wanted property; the other direction is similar.

When talking about categories, the formulation using splitting surjections is more natural than talking about choice functions and so on. So we formulate it by saying that every two surjections split.

Note that while the axiom of choice implies that given any two sets $|X|\leq|Y|$ or $|Y|\leq|X|$, and using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem we can say that if there are surjections from $X$ onto $Y$ **and vice versa** then the cardinals are equal; but this is certainly not true. It might be that every surjection from $X$ to $Y$ splits, but there is no bijection between them. For example if $X$ has two elements and $Y$ has just one.

The axiom, in general, has many many consequences. There are books which include consequences and equivalents of the axiom of choice, and I'm not sure which you'd like to hear about.

Finally, note that I was talking about sets, but the same can be said about classes or conglomerates.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for set theory as I have not had anything solid on set theory?

Comment: Maybe Enderton's book?